# calculating signature and showing group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I got this question in my group theory book. I think I understand the theory behind it but can't seem to use it to get a solution im happy with.

Let $V = M_2(\mathbb F)$. For $x,y \in V$ define $B(x,y) = det(x+y)-det(x)-det(y)$.

1. Show that $B$ is a symetric nondegenerate form on V, and calculate the signature of $B$ when $\mathbb F$=$\mathbb R$.
2. Let $G=SL(2,\mathbb F)\times SL(2,\mathbb F)$, and $\phi\colon G\rightarrow$ $GL(V)$ by $\phi(a,b)v=avb^t$ for $a,b \in SL(2,\mathbb F)$ and $v \in V$. show that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism and $\phi(G) \subset SO(V,B)$. determine $Ker(\phi)$ (I think you can determine this with jordan canonical form)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you call "form" to? It usually is bilinear but I don't think $\;B\;$ here is. Could it be you meant trace instead of determinant? Also your formula for $\;\phi\;$ in 2 seems to use a $\;x\;$ instead of $\;v\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc It's easy to check that it is. (And it's important that the matrices are $2\times 2$, not any bigger.)

Comment: I think i got the question correct, mind to explain that blue? I'm new to this subject, and could use some explaining. thanks!

Comment: Thankyou @blue: you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Do you know what you're trying to show? You want to show that $B(x,y)=B(y,x)$ (that's the symmetric part), that $B(u+v,w)=B(u,w)+B(v,w)$ and $B(\lambda x,y)=\lambda B(x,y)$ (this is linearity in the first argument; linearity in the second follows from symmetry), and that for all $x\in M_2(\Bbb F)$ there exists a $y\in M_2(\Bbb F)$ such that $B(x,y)\ne0$ (with symmetry, this means nondegeneracy).

In order to do these things, you're going to have to actually write out what $B(x,y)$ looks like explicitly when $x=(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})$, $y=(\begin{smallmatrix}\bar{a}&\bar{b}\\\bar{c}&\bar{d}\end{smallmatrix})$. In order to compute the signature of $B$, you need to compute the underlying matrix (this is easy), and then count the number of zeros which are positive, negative or zero. You can do this by computing the characteristic polynomial, which happens to be easy in this case, and then finding its roots.

(2) Specifying a group homomorphism $G\to{\rm GL}(V)$ means having a linear group action of $G$ on the space $V$. Check that $(a,b)v:=avb^t$ defines a group action of ${\rm SL}_2(\Bbb F)\times{\rm SL}_2(\Bbb F)$ on $V=M_2(\Bbb F)$, and then check that the action is linear, i.e. $(a,b)(v+w)=(a,b)v+(a,b)w$. This is just basic properties of matrix/vector multiplication.

The meaning of $\phi(G)\subset SO(V,B)$ is that (i) as a linear map on $V=M_2(\Bbb F)$, each $(a,b)\in G$ acts by a matrix with determinant $1$ (for which it suffices to check that each $(a,{\rm Id}_2)$ and $({\rm Id}_2,b)$ act by matrices of determinant $1$ - do you know why?), and (ii) $B((a,b)v,(a,b)w)=B(v,w)$ for every choice of $(a,b)\in G={\rm SL}_2(\Bbb F)\times{\rm SL}_2(\Bbb F)$ and $v,w\in M_2(\Bbb F)$. To do (i), notice that (say) the left action of ${\rm SL}_2(\Bbb F)$ on $M_2(\Bbb F)$ corresponds to two copies of ${\rm SL}_2(\Bbb F)$ acting on $\Bbb F^2$ (since it acts on the left and right columns of matrices in $M_2(\Bbb F)$ independently). To do (ii), use the product formula for determinants (i.e. $\det(uv)=\det(u)\det(v)$).

Finally, to compute $\ker\phi$, plug $x={\rm Id}_2$ into $axb^t=x$, simplify to $ax=xa^t$. Write this out in full, multiply out on both sides, equate both sides. Since $x$'s entries are unknowns, we can equate coefficients on both sides and solve for the entries of the matrix $a$. It will narrow down fairly quickly, and then you add in the fact $\det a=1$ and you'll be done.

Comment: When you say compute the signature by computing the underlying matrix, you mean I need to explicitly find $B(x,y)$ and find the roots of that matrix (does that what underlying matrix mean?)?

Comment: @Serph If we view $V$ as a vector space, and take the four elementary matrices as basis vectors, and represent the vectors in $V$ as column vectors, then any bilinear form looks like $x^tBy$ for some matrix $B$. (The matrix is not necessarily explicit or obvious when looking at the original bilinear form - indeed it depends on choice of basis, and you have to compute it. That's why it's "underlying"; it's not overt.) In this case, the matrix for $B$ will be a very simple $4\times4$ matrix.

Comment: now I'm even more confused, I thought I would get a 2 x 2 matrix.

Comment: @Serph $V$ is four-dimensional.

Comment: You explained the theory, and I think on the most part I understand it, though the calculations you mention are still hard for me, now that I read the whole thing a few times and tried it myself.. think you could show me specifically?

Comment: Indeed for every $x,y\in M_2(\Bbb F)$, we know $B(x,y)$ is a scalar. Did you not know what it means to find the matrix of a bilinear form? I explained it quickly just above, but you seem not to have read my comment. | The calculations are not hard, they are pretty easy. So you must just not know what you're supposed to be doing. That's why I went to the trouble of sketching everything out in my answer...

Comment: I confused $B$ with $B(x,y)$, my bad there.

Comment: Seph: Let me see that you've actually done something. Write out $B((\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}),(\begin{smallmatrix}\bar{a}& \bar{b}\\\bar{c}&\bar{d}\end{smallmatrix}))$ explicitly in a comment. Then we'll work on finding the matrix.

Comment: Well, it's $a$$\bar{d}$ + $\bar{a}$$d$ - $b$$\bar{c}$ - $\bar{b}$$c$

Comment: That's correct. Write down $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} ? & ? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ? & ? \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\bar{a} \\ \bar{b} \\ \bar{c} \\ \bar{d}\end{pmatrix} = a\bar{d}+\bar{a}d-b\bar{c}-\bar{b}c$$ Now fill in the blanks.

Comment: so i get a matrix with  1,-1,-1,1 on 14,23,32,41 places. like the diagonal which is not the main one

Comment: Right. Now what's the characteristic polynomial of that matrix?

Comment: its $x^4 -1$, sothe roots are 1 and -1 for $\mathbb R$?

Comment: That's not the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Why not? $det(B-XI)$=0 is the characteristic polynomal, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's how the characteristic polynomial is defined. But you don't get $x^4-1$.

Comment: Do you get $x^4+1$ ?

Comment: Nope, that's also incorrect.

Comment: Well, I suppose I have some mistake I can't find.Thanks for trying to help anyways.

Comment: I tried again, got $x^4 -2x^2 +1$. if that is not  correct, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: That's correct now. What are the roots of that polynomial (counting them with multiplicity)? Finding them should be an easy matter of factoring.

Comment: it's $(x-1)^2(x+1)^2$, so roots are 1 and -1 2 times each

Comment: @Serph Correct, so the signature is (2,2) [two positive and two negative]

Comment: Great. Much appreciated.